# How to read from a pdf and use it as a blob

Tags: blob, java-io, apache-tika

All:

I am pretty new to Java IO, right now what I need to do is to read a blob object( it is a PDF file retrieved from Database) and send it to Apache Tika to parse.

But I do not have the access to that blob object right now( need to wait for other team to pass it), so in order to figure out my part ahead of time( read blob, turn it into inputstream, feed it to Tika), I wonder how can I build a blob from a PDF file? And I am kinda wondering how to convert that blob into inputstream, any help?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with [Blob.getBinaryStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream%28%29)?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks. I am pretty new to JAVA, dont know it has API for it. BTW, how can I build a BLOB object from an PDF if I want to test first